# Migration from Javascript to Typescript (AngularJS to Angular4)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am trying to migrate JavaScript to TypeScript (AngularJS to Angular4).

Code snippet from JavaScript:

```
var className = eval('MethodName');
var data = new className();
```

In, Typescript code I have migrated as below,

```
let code = ts.transpile('MethodName');
var className = eval(code);
var data = new className();
```

I am facing the below error:

```
ReferenceError: MethodName is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.ts:457), <anonymous>:1:1)
at main.ts:457
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Editor.webpackJsonp.603.Editor.loadPlugins (main.ts:452)
at Editor.<anonymous> (main.ts:123)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:495)
```

I have imported the class inside TypeScript file.

```
import * as ts from 'Typescript';
import { MethodName } from './method.ts';
```

Comment: What is `'MethodName'`? Why do you need to use `eval`?

Comment: 'MethodName' is Class name and I am trying to migrate from angularjs javascript to angular4 typescript. In javascript code used eval. I don't know how to use eval in angular4 and need to call the specific class.

Comment: I hope you have not exported the class MethodName as default? If so then remove the curly brackets while importing.

Comment: Why can't you just do `new MethodName()`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I done that using new MethodName(). But, I want to store all the functions in the class to the variable.

Comment: @VishalGulati, I have exported methodname as default and removed the curly brackets while importing. But, still same issue.